# SQL: get product stock of all product types in a single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I want to get stock information for all the products depending upon the product type.
The tables are `products`, `product_stocks`, `complex1_childs` & `complex2_childs`.
**products**

```
| product_id | type      |
|------------|-----------|
| 100        | simple    |
| 101        | simple    |
| 103        | complex_1 |
| 104        | simple    |
| 105        | complex_2 |
| 106        | complex_1 |
| 107        | simple    |
| 108        | simple    |
| 109        | simple    |
```

The available product types are:

- simple
- complex_1
- complex_2

`complex_*` type is a compound product which includes other products as a child.

**product_stocks**

```
| product_id | qty |
|------------|-----|
| 100        | 10  |
| 101        | 50  |
| 104        | 10  |
| 107        | 25  |
| 108        | 100 |
| 109        | 40  |
```

As you can see only `simple` product type have qty info.

**complex1_childs**

```
| parent_id | child_id |
|-----------|----------|
| 103       | 101      |
| 106       | 107      |
| 106       | 101      |
```

Child products are always simple type.

**complex2_childs**

```
| parent_id | child_id |
|-----------|----------|
| 105       | 107      |
| 105       | 108      |
```

Child products are always simple type.

Now I want to get stock information for all the products as:

```
| product_id | final_qty |
|------------|-----------|
| 100        | 10        |
| 101        | 50        |
| 103        | 50        |
| 104        | 10        |
| 105        | 125       |
| 106        | 75        |
| 107        | 25        |
| 108        | 100       |
| 109        | 40        |
```

Note that qty for `complex_*` product types are calculated as sum of their child products' qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have effectively have these 3 queries:

simple

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(s.qty) AS final_qty
FROM products AS p
JOIN product_stocks AS s
  ON p.product_id = s.product_id AND
     p.type = 'simple'
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

complex 1:

```
SELECT p.product_id, SUM(s.qty) AS final_qty
FROM products AS p
JOIN complex1_childs AS c
  ON p.product_id = c.parent_id AND
     p.type = 'complex_1'
JOIN products AS cp
  ON c.child_id = cp.product_id
JOIN product_stocks AS s
  ON cp.product_id = s.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

complex 2 is the same as above changing the table and the p.type join criteria.

You can [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) these together into a single query.

Answer (score 0):

select (CurrentPrimaryStock-AllocatedAgainstInStock) as CurrentInstock,(CurrentTertiaryStock -AllocatedAgainstTertiary) as currentbackorder,p.SKU,p.Name,ps.MetalComposition as Metal,ItemWeight as weight,
vw.ProductType as ProductTypeName,vm.MintName,vg.Grade as GradeName,vs.Series as SeriesName,CountryName,vr.Region as RegionName
from Products p
inner join ProductInventory pe on p.id=pe.ProductId
inner join ProductStats ps on p.id=ps.ProductId
inner join ProductSearchAttributes psa on p.id=psa.ProductId
inner join VW_ProductTypes vw on psa.ProductTypeId=vw.ProductTypeId
inner join VW_Mints vm on psa.MintId=vm.MintId
inner join vw_Grades vg on psa.GradeId=vg.GradeId
inner join vw_series vs on psa.SeriesId=vs.SeriesId
inner join VW_Region vr on psa.RegionId=vr.RegionId

Comment: Hi Aditya, its unreadable. Please edit it and format it. Start off by putting 3 backticks on their own line, before and after the sql.